# Improper integral Riemann sum limit in the derivation of Fourier series to Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-sum

To give background to my question, in all the books I've looked at to derive the inverse Fourier transform of a continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, they seem to work as follows. Let $k$ be a positive real number and write (by standard Fourier series theory)
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n \, e^{i n \pi x/k}\ ,
$$
where
$$
c_n = \frac{1}{2k} \int_{-k}^k f(y) \, e^{-i n \pi y/k}\, dy\ 
$$
Let $\xi_n = n \pi / k$ and $\Delta \xi_n = \xi_n - \xi_{n-1} = \pi/k$, then
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty
\left( \int_{-k}^k f(y) \, e^{-i y \xi_n}\, d y \right) e^{i x  \xi_n } \Delta \xi_n.
$$
Take $k \to \infty$ to get
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \widehat{f}(\xi)\, e^{i x \xi}\, d \xi
$$
where
$$
\widehat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  f(x)\, e^{-ix \xi} \,d x.
$$
Everyone does this argument, but they never prove it. Even if a book says this argument is not rigorous, they never once give a counterexample.

My Question is about the proof: Let $g(\xi)$ be absolutely integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ and continuous, but NOT compactly supported, for otherwise my question is trivial. Let $k > 0$, let $\xi_n = n/k$, and consider the Riemann sum 
$$
\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty g(\xi_n)\Delta \xi_n
$$
where suppose that this infinite series is absolutely convergent for all $k > 0$.   Must it be true that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{-\infty}^\infty g(\xi_n)\Delta \xi_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(\xi) d \xi?
$$
If this is true, can you give an elementary proof, a proof using only the theory of the Riemann integral and no measure theory or other advanced stuff? If not, what is an explicit and not too complicated counterexample?

Comment: Did you mean $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{-k}^{k}g(\xi_n)\Delta \xi_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(\xi) d \xi$$?

Comment: No, I meant it exactly as stated. Note that the $\xi_n = n/k$ depends on $k$. This is what you are taking the limit of, not the limits of integration.

Comment: Ok. Then the equality holds if g is absolutely integrable and compactly supported, for other functions that derivation is wrong because the equality doesn't always hold?

Comment: Anyway, you might be interested in http://links.uwaterloo.ca/amath391w13docs/boggess_narcowich.pdf
Check chapter 2 for informal derivation of Fourier transform and Appendix A for formal derivation of Fourier transform. I'm not a mathematician, but I recently was asking the same question. As you can see, the informal derivation is wrong (that's why it's informal, it's just there to give you an idea of how Fourier series and Fourier transform are related). It's just my opinion though.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly convergence of the Riemann sums does not follow from integrability and continuity of $g$.

Consider this function $g$:

[image: graph]

Spikes of decreasing width.  Area of the spike centered at $m\pi$ is $1/2^m$.  We have:

$\bullet $ $g$ is continuous

$\bullet $ $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |g(\xi)|\;d\xi = 1$

$\bullet $ $g(m\pi) = 1$ for $m=1,2,3,\dots$;

$\bullet $ $g(x) \ge 0$ for $-\infty < x < \infty$.

Now fix $k \in \mathbb N$.  For $m=1,2,3\dots$ we have $\xi_{mk} = m\pi$, and there are infinitely many of these, so
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} g(\xi_n)\Delta \xi_n = 
\frac{\pi}{k}\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(\xi_n) \ge 
\frac{\pi}{k}\sum_{m=1}^\infty g(m\pi) = +\infty .
$$

Comment: To complete the right answer of GEdgar, if $h$ is the function with a single spike at the origin, an explicit example of a function such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_n g(\xi_n)\Delta\xi_n \neq \int g\,d\xi$ is $g=\sum_{k,n}\frac{1}{2^k}h(k2^n(x-n/k))$.

Comment: Excuse me, the example of GEdgar was completely right.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks. In my question I required that the sum g(xi_n) delta xi_n had to be absolutely convergent for all k (to omit examples such as the one you gave). Is there an example with the Riemann sums abs convergent?